# Calling ko.toJS on Breeze entity causes slow long running script

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze

When calling `ko.toJS(entity)` on any Breeze entity that has navigation properties or is part of a large object graph IE7-8 complain of long running script errors and even chrome can get bogged down for over 1 second.

### What gives?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had this plague me before and seen various forums or Github issues where this became an issue for devs.  I wanted to share some knowledge in hopes that it helps others.

**The problem**

Breeze.js provides your client-side libraries or frameworks with an object graph.  Calling JSON.stringify() on the entity will cause the dreaded stack overflow because some of the properties reference each other.  Example -

`Person -> Company -> Persons`

Since a person has a navigation property of company that also has a navigation property of persons they continue to find each other.

ko.toJS() gets around this by detecting duplicates and stopping the serialization at that point.

**Why is it slow?**

The serialization takes longer depending on the number of entities in the object graph.  Don't believe me?  Load your app and call ko.toJS() then go load up a bunch more entities in the same object graph.  It will take longer, guaranteed.  The problem is that even if you call ko.toJS() on a single person Knockout isn't finding duplicates until it has serialized *every person in the original persons company*.  This isn't a problem of Knockout nor Breeze - it is caused by how well interconnected everything is.

**What can I do to fix it?**

Using a projection query is the best solution, if you can.  The problem is usually we need deeper nested levels of entities, not just the current entity.  If your entity has a navigation property that has many related entities there is no easy way to perform a projection query, so we need to take it a step further in one of two manners -

1. Write a custom serializer
2. [Vote for IdeaBlade (the company behind Breeze.js) to support unwrapping more efficiently](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3893781-expose-a-method-on-the-entitymanager-to-unwrap-a)

My opinion - expose a method on the entity manager to 'unwrap' that accepts the following parameters -

`entityManager.unwrap(entity || [entities], [addtlTypesToUnwrap])`

Where addtlTypesToUnwrap is either an array of strings or comma separated strings that define which related entity types to unwrap.

Example usage -

```
var thisEntity = manager.fetchEntityByKey('Person', 1, true);
var relatedProps = ['Company', 'Address']
entityManager.unwrap(thisEntity, relatedProps);
```

Which would unwrap Person, their address, their company, and the companies address (if it existed)

Comment: brilliant fix. Was looking for that for a while.:)