# Breeze preloading unwanted nvaigation properties

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I am using Entity Framework 6.1 with breeze 1.4.11. I am trying to save some data in local storage. My Breeze controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public object Lookups()
    {
        return new
        {
            lookupItems = _contextProvider.Context.LookupItem
        };
    }
```

My EF settings:

```
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

The class I am trying to load:

```
public class LookupItem : BaseEntityInt
{

    public int LookupTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Ordinal { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Party> PartyCountries { get; set; }

}
```

My breeze client code:

```
_lookupsQuery = new breeze.EntityQuery.from("Lookups"),
em.executeQuery(_lookupsQuery).then(function (data) {
                            _lookups = data.results;
                            // Save data to local storage
                            store.setItem("Lookups", _lookups); // Fails here
});
```

The problem is when I save it in local storage, store uses amplifyJs to persist to local storage. AmplifyJs calls JSON.stringify on the persisted object. In the console of the browser I get the following error:

Error: cyclic object value

This is because breeze is automatically loading the navigation property of lookupitem 'partycountries' which itself links back to lookupitem. Anyone any idea why it is doing this? My understanding was you had to explicityly use eager loading or using the expand property (which I am not using) so I can't understand why it is having this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

**The why it is happening can be explained here -**
[Calling ko.toJS on Breeze entity causes slow long running script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550560/calling-ko-tojs-on-breeze-entity-causes-slow-long-running-script)

To get around it I believe you can over-ride the toString method on the entities that you are trying to serialize so that it ignores related navigation properties.

The reason I didn't mark this as a duplicate is you are using Amplify.js and some other users in the future might as well.

Answer (score 0):

I can assure you Breeze is not loading the related `PartyCountries`. Either your server api is including them along with the "Lookups" query payload or you queried them into cache earlier and Breeze wired them up to you "Lookups" as they arrived. Based on the code you're showing us, I'd guess that you loaded `PartyCountries` earlier in the `em` (EntityManager) lifetime.

You might let Breeze serialize the entities for you. It takes care of circular references, won't include related entities, and also stores the changed-state with the serialized entities.

For example, with [**Amplify.store**](http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/#amplifystore):

```
var exported = em.exportEntities(data.results, false /* exclude metadata */);
// Save data to local storage
store("Lookups", exported ); // Works!
```

Later you can retrieve and import them:

```
var imported = store("Lookups"); 
var importedEntities = em.importEntities(imported);
```

You can store an entire graph of entities (e.g., an order and its line items) with the help of the [Breeze Labs "getEntityGraph" extension](http://www.breezejs.com/breeze-labs/getentitygraph). Here it is applied to your model.

```
// graph of queried `LookupItems` and their in-cache, related 'PartyCountries'
var graph = em.getEntityGraph(data.results, 'PartyCountries'); 

var exported = em.exportEntities(graph , false /* exclude metadata */);
store("LookupsAndCountries", exported );
```

Comment: Thanks, in the end I did something similar to this. I exported the entityManager and stored using amplify. Later on retrieved the em and then ran the query locally to get the lookups I wanted. I'll have a look at the getEntityGraph. I still don't see how I loaded PartyCountries. I haven't used this, its just for ef to create a relationship and isn't used anywhere else in the app. Thanks

Comment: Check the payloads from the server. SOMETHING is putting PartyCountries in cache. Breeze won't do it on its own (BreezeJS doesn't support lazy loading). Note also that `importEntities` returns the entities it imported so you shouldn't have to requery the `em`.